# Where's the textures folder?

Tags: texturing, file-browser

At 13:05 in [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6lSfOfiXHY&feature=youtu.be), Steve adds an image texture in node wrangler from a textures folder. I searched my computer for 2 hours in the Blender Foundation folder, and could not find any "textures" folder. Where is it? He chose a Metalbare.jpg file from it.  Zero search results for that file also. Can anyone tell me where to find these?

Answer (score 2):

These textures don't come with Blender, so you won't ever find them in your Blender installation.

The textures are linked to in the video's description (click "Show More" underneath the video):

[MetalBare0154.jpg](http://www.textures.com/download/metalbare0154/55198)

[Smoke0379.jpg](http://www.textures.com/download/smoke0379/43662)